# Como posso setar a largura de cada coluna em um GridView?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

Como posso setar a largura de cada coluna em um `GridView` no seguinte caso abaixo?

```
 <div style="width: 1000px; height: 400px; overflow: scroll">
    <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="6"
      HeaderStyle-CssClass="Cabec">
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
        Nenhum Registro Encontrado
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome Filial" DataField="NomeFilial" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
          ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nr Titulo " DataField="NrTitulo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  HeaderStyle-Width="250px" ItemStyle-Width="250px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Dt Emissão" DataField="DtEmissao" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}"
          HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Dt Vencimento" DataField="DtVencimento" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}"
          HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor Titulo" DataField="ValorTitulo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Dias Vencido" DataField="DiasVencido" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor Bruto Titulo" DataField="ValorBrutoTitulo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor Baixado" DataField="ValorBaixado" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor Receber" DataField="ValorReceber" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ocorrência Geral" DataField="OcorrenciaGeral" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Razão Social" DataField="RazaoSocial" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome Obra" DataField="NomeObra" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome" DataField="Nome" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tipo Cobrança" DataField="TipoCobranca" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
  </div>
```

Já tentei por `ItemStyle-Width="150px"` e o `HeaderStyle-Width="250px"`, mas as colunas não respeitam o tamanho definido conforme a imagem abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero definir um tamanho para cada coluna de forma que tanto o cabeçalho quanto os itens tenham um tamanho razoável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HeaderStyle-CssClass="larguraMinima` e crie o css:

```
.larguraMinima{
     min-width: 140px;
}
```